# Java passing value from array to new object instance

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

I have some issues with the passing array values to the constructor. I have a `file.txt` which contains some lines with values, for example:

> peter|berlin|germany|0930295235|foo.

I figured out how to transform the lines into the arrays. But I don't know how to pass the values from arrays to the constructor to transform the arrays into the objects with the array attributes.

Here is the main class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Open the file that is the first 
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            // Read the file line by line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Print the content on the console
                String s[] = strLine.split("\\|");
                // System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s));
                // System.out.println (strLine);
                for (String element : s) {
                    System.out.println(element);
                    // HERE I NEED TO PASS THE ARRAY VALUES FOR EACH LINE TO TRANSFORM THE ARRAYS TO OBJECTS
                    Item item = new Item(element,element,element,element,element);
                    System.out.println("*************************************");
                }
                // Close the input stream
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { //Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class Item:

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String number;
    private String foo;

    public Object(String name, String city, String state, String number,String foo){
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.number = number;
        this.foo = foo; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

I need objects for more work with the data. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Choose a better name for your class that describes what it is for, don't confuse it with the one that already exist

Comment: You should not be calling your class `Object` - that's a Java superclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like the following, although it's not entirely clear.

```
String s[] = strLine.split("\\|");
Item item = new Item(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]);
```

Also note that after you've created your new `Item` object it will fall out of scope nearly immediately, so you need to store it in some sort of container declared outside of your `while` loop:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = line.split("\\|");
    Item item = new Item(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4]);
    items.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need this `for` loop.

```
for(String element : s)
{
}
```

If you are looking to extract particular `String`s from the array you should use something like,

```
String name = s[0];
```

but be careful not to select items outside the range of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s[] = strLine.split("\\|");
Object item = new Object(s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a for loop there, just pass each array value to the `Object`s constructor, having first checked that you have the right number of values. The new `Object` is already used in Java, so call your class (rembember the difference between object and class), `MyObj`.

```
MyObj myObj = null; // De
String s[] = strLine.split("\\|");
if (s.length==5){
  myObj = new MyObj(s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4]);
} else {
  System.err.println("Wrong number of arguments on the line"+strLine);
}
```

It might be clearly to use a constructor with no parameters and then set each of fields with

```
myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.setName( s[0]); //etc
```

Which is slight more readable, as to which data goes into which field

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the for loop to:

```
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i+=5) {
      System.out.println(s[i]);
      Object item = new Object(s[i],s[i+1],s[i+2],s[i+3],s[i+4]);
 }
```

But this assumes size of 's' is of form 5n; n being 1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the structure of `file.txt`, and *thus* the length of `String[] s`, you can call each element of the arrays you have:

```
for (String element : s) {
    System.out.println(element);
    Item item = new Item(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]);
}
```

In order to save the `Item item`s and not overwrite them with the next element in the loop, you can save it to an array with your items (start with declaring an array):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        ...
```

and then

```
for (String element : s) {
    System.out.println(element);
    Item item = new Item(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]);
    items.add(item);
}
```